# Do we have a tag policy?

Tags: discussion, tags

Browsing around, I periodically find tags that I find odd. The latest two come from [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/27625/revisions): [ethnic-terms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethnic-terms) and [ethnonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethnonyms).

These seem borderline to me but I can see myself getting tired of pinging Meta every time I want to ask about a tag. Do we have a good rule of thumb for what tags we want? (Perhaps an appropriate Meta.SO thread I can use?)

Answer (score 4):

You usually add tags for which you expect questions using them. In this case, I would not expect many questions about ethnonyms.

The function of tags is classifying the questions, but not classifying them too granularly. It would not make sense to use [fruit-nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruit-nouns), [boat-nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boat-nouns), [animal-nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-nouns), when there is already [nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns).

On meta.stackoverflow.com, there is a question about appropriate tag usage, which is specific for *Stack Overflow*, but which could make some aspects of using tags clearer: [What is considered appropriate tag use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17706/what-is-considered-appropriate-tag-use)